# Can an app suppress iOS's multitasking gestures?

Tags: ios, multitasking-gestures

Is there a way to suppress gesture recognition? What inspires me to ask this question is watching my grand-daughter, who is a toddler, using an iPad. Quite often, she will accidentally invoke a gesture recognizer that switches apps. An example of this would be the four finger gesture where you can slide an app out of the way.

For a "child proof" app, is it possible to suppress these? Failing that, is it possible to suppress switching to another app? At first thought, that seems out of scope of an app, but maybe there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do it in your app, because it is an accessibility feature of iOS 6. It is called "Guided Access" and you can enable it in Settings -> General -> Accessibility in the Learning section.

Comment: Is it available in iOS5? I ask because my daughter has not upgraded yet because of youtube.

Comment: No, it was added in iOS6. YouTube isn't that important :)

Comment: Heh, it is for some people. Anyway, there are two iPads in her household. Last I knew, one was kept on iOS5 for youtube. The other was upgraded to iOS6. After I installe Chrome on mine, I had perfectly acceptable youtube. Maybe Google has come out with a full sized iPad app for youtube by now. That's what my daughter was waiting for. Anyway, don't want to get too sidetracked.

Comment: Understood. I use the Guided Access with my daughter and it works great. I made an app for her, and I use it with GarageBand also. You can even set it up as a triple-click of the home button for easy access.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement, but you cannot override the gesture recognition. It takes priority over your app.
Actually I wanted to do an app for my baby and had the same requirement!, but you cannot disable the gesture recognition on a non jail broken device ;(

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can turn off it in [settings manually](http://0.tqn.com/d/ipad/1/0/e/2/-/-/multitasking-gestures.PNG). Go to settings> general> Multitasking gestures. I dont think we can control this via coding for normal apps, but you can inform the user to disable it here through an alert before using the app. That is the most appropriate way available now.

Comment: If I could check two answers, I would. I consider this just as valid as the one I checked.

Comment: @VictorEngel, Thanks victor. Glad to know that it helped.  That is fine. :)